# Jquery Append Existing element

Tags: jquery, append

Jquery `.append()` method:
"Insert content, specified by the parameter, TO THE END(!!!) of each element in the set of matched elements." [Api](https://api.jquery.com/append/)

First, adds to the END (ok):

```js
 var tbody = $('tbody');
 var row = $('<tr><td>4</td></tr>');

  tbody.append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  
 <tr><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

Second, replaces everything (doesn't add to the end):

```js
 var tbody = $('tbody');
 var row = tbody.children('tr:first');

  tbody.append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  
 <tr><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```

If target.append(element) should add element to the end of target, second example should output `1 2 3 1`, and not `2 3 1`.

QUESTION: Why does the second example output 2 3 1?

Answer (score 1):

`append`removes elements from the dom before appending them. If you want to retain the original element where it is, you need to clone it first, then append the clone.

Comment: thanks, I haven't found that in the documentation (link above). Do you use any documentation for Jquery?)

Comment: @SergejFomin there a like two lines at abotu 1/3rd page height which goes like `If an element selected this way is inserted into a single location elsewhere in the DOM, it will be moved into the target (not cloned):` there is about the only clue.  I merely ran into the same problem before overlooking that line in the docs

Answer (score 1):

You should add clone for tr

```js
var tbody = $('tbody');
var row = tbody.children('tr:first').clone();
tbody.append(row);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
 <tbody>
  
 <tr><td>1</td></tr>
 <tr><td>2</td></tr>
 <tr><td>3</td></tr>

 </tbody>
</table>
```